# How to send mix of GET and POST in python

Tags: python, post, get, request, python-requests

I'm trying to send a mix of GET and POST to a URL using requests module. Is there a way to do this?

What I 've tried is the following:

```
import requests

payload = {'test': 'test'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post?key1=val1&key2=val2",params=payload)

print r.text
```

but when I see what is actually being sent to the server (i.e. r.text), I see that everything is being sent via POST.

Could someone tell me how I can get key1 and key2 to get sent via GET and test to be sent via POST please?

I tried to look for this on Google and on StackOveflow but couldn't find anything...

EDIT: To clarify what I'm attempting to do, what I would like is to replicate the following request that gets sent to a website: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/638729/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-04%20at%2008.43.49.png

Thank you
Tak

Comment: Does it matter? You'll get the data however the browser decies to encode it. This looks more like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); Please describe your *actual* problem.

Comment: GET and POST are different types of requests. You can't "combine" them into a single request.

Comment: Well strictly speaking they are teh same kind of request but with a different "method" name. The requests library is likely taking the query-string parameters and form parameters and merging them together into a single structure.

Comment: Pick one; either use ``data`` or "query-string" parameters; not both.

Comment: Thank you both. You may be right about the XY problem: what I'm trying to do is to replicate the following request that's being sent in the browser: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/638729/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-04%20at%2008.43.49.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't literally have what you ask for. A request is either GET or POST, not both. However, I *think* you are asking if some of the parameters can be encoded in the URL while others are form-encoded in the payload.

Try this:

```
import requests

params = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
payload = {'test': 'test'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post",params=params,data=payload)

print r.text
```

Comment: Sorry to be naïve. What's the difference between params and data...?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface), "params – (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent in the query string for the Request." and "
data – (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request."  So the difference is that one goes in the query string and other goes in the body.